# Send Mails with Postfix through SSH Tunnel

Tags: postfix, dovecot, ssh-tunnel

I'm a bloody newbie to SMTP and Postfix but I have configured a Postfix SMTP Service with SASL authentication on Raspbian in a local network behind a firewall. 
There is also a Dovecat IMAP Server running on the same instance.
I setted up reverse SSH Tunnels to to route incoming traffic on a external Server with static IPv4 to the Email Server Ports on the Raspberry.
I configured also an Emailaccount in Thunderbird to test my configurations with.

These are different things i tried in my tunnelscript:

Like this i can send and receive my mails. The problem here is, that the mails to send, will be send with the dynamic ip of the local network and i want them to be send through the external server.

```
 /usr/bin/autossh -p26 -fN -R :465:localhost:465 -R :25:localhost:25 -R :993:localhost:993 xxxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Here is my attempt to solve the Problem: So we have mail traffic going out from the Postfix Server on the Raspberry, that means that this Port must be forwareded to the external Server to have that IP after arriving at the receiver (right?). That means i have to forward a local port. But like this Thunderbird tells me, that it cant establish a connection to the smtp server anymore.

```
 /usr/bin/autossh -p26 -fN -L :465:localhost:465 -L :25:localhost:25 -R :993:localhost:993 xxxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Is there a way to send and receive mails through a ssh tunnel from a Postfix/Dovecot Server without setting up a Mail Relay? For that i would have to install a second Instance of Postfix on the External Server, is that right?

Thanks for your interest and your help

Comment: Did you try using -L instead of -R?